# hadoop nodes with Linux + windows

Tags: linux, windows, hadoop

I have 4 windows machines, On which i have installed hadoop on 3 out of 4. 
One machine having the Harton work Sandbox ( say for 4-th machine) , Now i need to make the  4th machine as my server ( Name node )
and rest of the machine as slaves.

- Whether it will work if i update the configuration files in the rest of 3 machines
- Or is there any other way to do this ?
- Any other suggestions ?

Thanks

finally i got this but i could not find any help

[Hadoop cluster configuration with Ubuntu Master and Windows slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301109/hadoop-cluster-configuration-with-ubuntu-master-and-windows-slave)

Answer (score 1):

A non-secure cluster will work (non-secure in the sense that you do not enable Hadoop Kerberos based auth and security, ie. `hadoop.security.authentication` is left as `simple`). You need to update all nodes config to point to the new 4th node as the master for various services you plan to host on it. You mention namenode, but I assume you really mean to make the 4th node the 'head' node, meaning it will probably also run resourcemanager and historyserver (or the jobtracker for old-style Hadoop). And that is only core, w/o considering higher level components like Hive, Pig, Oozie etc, and not even mentioning Ambari or Hue.

Doing a post-install configuration of existing Windows (or Linux, makes no difference) nodes is possible, editing the various xx-site.xml files. You'll have to know what to change and is not trivial. Probably it would be much easier to just deploy again the windows machines, with an appropriate clusterproperties.txt config file. See [Option III - Manual Install One Node At A Time](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-Win-1.1.0/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/content/win-install-chap2-3.html).